# merge callback function result with call limit

Tags: javascript

**Disclaimer**: This was an interview question I was asked today. However, I do think there are real world use cases.

Supposedly, we have a function called `helperLimit`, it takes in 4 params. This function will merge list of results from multiple callback functions.

**args:** an array of argument (IDs)

**limit:** number of callback function can be fire at any given time

**fn:** a callback function that takes arg (ID) and a callback as param

**done:** a callback merges all async results from list of calls using each arg (ID)

I can come up with partial answer but I don't know how to handle the rate limit control portion of the question.

```js
// This function works except the limit part
function helperLimit(args, limit, fn, done) {
  const final = [];
  let complete = args.length;
  
  for (let currentIndex = 0; currentIndex < args.length; currentIndex++) {
    fn(args[currentIndex], (result) => {
      final[currentIndex] = result;
      complete--;
      
      if (complete === 0) {
        done(final)
      }
    })
  }
}

// simulate API calls
function getById(id, callback) {
  const random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000) + 5;
  setTimeout(() => {
    callback({id, result: `result ${id}`});
  }, random)
}


helperLimit([1,2,3,4,5], 2, getById, (result) => { console.log(result); })
```

Thank you in advance for providing helps.

Comment: As far as I understand:  `let complete = args.length > limit ? limit : args.length;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To implement the `limit` feature, call the function at most `limit` times in the loop. Then in the callback that you have for `fn`, call `fn` again (once) until you have covered all calls:

```
function helperLimit(args, limit, fn, done) {
  const final = [];
  let stillToComplete = args.length;

  limit = Math.min(limit, args.length);
  let currentIndex = 0;
  while (currentIndex < limit) perform(currentIndex++);
  
  function perform(index) {
    fn(args[index], (result) => {
      final[index] = result;
      stillToComplete--;      
      if (stillToComplete) {
        if (currentIndex < args.length) perform(currentIndex++);
      } else {
        done(final);
      }
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much!